# Get jpg images from a bag file python bagpy

Tags: python, bag

I have a bag file with several frames. I need to extract that in python. I tried rosbag package but it seems that there's no compatibility with python >3.7. Bagpy is another solution but is possible to extract the frames with this package?

Comment: Extract what type of data?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Ideally I want to extract jpg or png from a specific topic inside the bag file